# How to plot with different colors

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a spiral with 8 turns. In each turn it is supposed to have a different color.

```
t = -1*pi*1:0.02:pi*1;

plot3(sin(t),cos(t),-1*pi*1:0.02:pi*1,'g')

t1 = -1*pi*2:0.02:pi*2;

plot3(sin(t1),cos(t1),-2*pi*1:0.02:pi*2,'r')
```

For now i am only plotting two turns, but it just turns out red. I have tried using `hold on` and `hold off` but its not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show us your code with `hold on` and `hold off`

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
plot3(sin(t),cos(t),-1*pi*1:0.02:pi*1,'g-',sin(t1),cos(t1),-2*pi*1:0.02:pi*2,'r--')
```

Comment: Some explanation wouldn't hurt

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your red plot actually plots overtop of your previous one you should increase BOTH the lower bound and upper bound.

```
numberOfColors = 5;

for n = 0:numberOfColors-1
    t = -pi + n*2*pi:0.02:pi + n*2*pi;
    plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t,'Color',rand(3,1))
    hold on
end
```